# error: ‘List’ is not a template type

Tags: c++, g++

I am a beginner in c++ so please excuse me if I my mistakes below turn out to be silly. Still, I am stuck with my code and would appreciate any help.

I get the following error when trying to compile through make via g++:

```
In file included from A.cpp:2:
List.h:20: error: ‘List’ is not a template type
A.cpp: In member function ‘void A::NowyObiekt(int)’:
A.cpp:6: error: ‘list_a’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [A.o] Error 1
```

My code is separated into the following *tiny* files:

- A.h : http://pastebin.com/QQ04xx2j (header)
- A.cpp : below

  ```
  #include "A.h"
  #include "List.h"

  void A::NewObject(int i)
  {
          list_a.Add(i);
  }

  int A::Compare(int a, int b)
  {
          if ( a>b ) return 1;
          if ( a<b ) return -1;
          else return 0;
  }
  ```
- List.h : below (header)

  ```
  #ifndef LIST_H
  #define LIST_H
  template<typename T>
  class Node
  {
      Node()
      {
          nxt = pre = 0;
      }
      Node(const T& el, Node *n = 0, Node *p = 0 )
      {
          dana = el; nxt = n; pre = p;
      }
      T dana;
      Node *nxt, *pre;
  };

  template<typename T>
  class List
  {
  public:
      List()
      {
          head = tail = 0;
      }
      void Add(const T&);
  protected:
      Node<T> *head,*tail;
  };

  #endif
  ```
- List.cpp : http://pastebin.com/a3HQ9yZ4
- prog.cpp : below (main)

  ```
  #include "List.h"
  #include "A.h"

  int main()
  {
      int i = 5;
      class List list_a;
      class A obj;

      obj.Add(i);
  }
  ```
- and the makefile is : http://pastebin.com/GTR5jW54

As noted, I am still a beginner, so please be understanding. I would be thankful for any help and clear explanations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of links to pastebin, put some minimal code here which causes this error.

Comment: Should I put all of them or only those mentioned as causing problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code: The first is that you don't declare any variable named `list_a` anywhere. That error should be pretty obvious. The other is that you use the `List` class without giving it template parameters.

And last a small note about your question: As your files are indeed very small, you could put them in the question and not link to them.

**Edit:** About the `List`  template problem.

You already use `Node` properly in `List`, i.e. declare the nodes as `Node<T>`. When you use `List` you simply has to do the same. For example, to declare a list of integers:

```
List<int> my_int_list;
```

Also, as you only use public functions in `List` from the class `A`, you don't need the `friend` declaration. If you *do* need to use protected or private members (which IMO is a sign of bad design) you need to make that friend-declaration templated as well:

```
friend class List<sometype>;
```

And finally, your code will not compile anyway... The reason being that when you are using a template-class, the whole class has to be fully defined (i.e. complete with its function implementations). You can solve this by putting the functions in the header file. And when defining the functions, you need the template parameter there as well:

```
template<typename T>
void List<T>::Add(const T& el)
{
    Node<T>* head = new Node<T>(el);
    if ( Compare(el,i) > i )
        std::cout << "Ok" << std::endl;
}
```

Note that I added the template parameter in a couple of places.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. The problem is that I did declare this variable in main (file: prog.cpp), what should I do more with it then? As far as List problem is concerned, could you please be a bit more specific what exactly should I do? I'm a newbe.

Comment: @anonymous_infoholic change `class List list_a;` to `List<int> list_a` and in general, don't use the `class` keyword while declaring variables.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved the problem with templates. However, the list_a remains undeclared according to g++ even after applying all of the above.

Comment: @anonymous_infoholic Yes, because you _never declare_ any such variable anywhere.

Comment: I've put `List<int> list_a;` in prog.cpp as advised.

Comment: @anonymous_infoholic As a global variable? Then you need to declare it `extern` in `A.cpp` to be able to access it: `extern List<int> list_a;`